# Erlang "host key verification" error

Tags: testing, erlang, tsung, erlang-shell

I'm new in tsung and erlang and I want to distribution on tsung.
When I use this command:

```
ardic@base-64-arcsp:~/tsungtest$ erl -rsh ssh -name ardic@tsung  -setcookie tsung"
Erlang R13B03 (erts-5.7.4) [source] [64-bit] [rq:1] [async-threads:0] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V5.7.4  (abort with ^G)
(ardic@tsung)1> slave:start(tsungnode2,ardic,"-setcookie tsung").
"{error,timeout}
```

I took this error.

And I did everything in tsung FAQ about error, timeout.
Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I met the same error on my virtual ubuntu, and at last I found: virtual ubuntu can be master but not be slave (another centos can be slave or master ). I do not know why . I'll join the mail list to ask for more help.

> =INFO REPORT==== 28-Mar-2012::01:00:09 ===
>       ts_os_mon_erlang:(3:<0.2713.0>) Fail to start beam on host "centos-181" ({error,
>                                                                                 timeout})
>
> =ERROR REPORT==== 28-Mar-2012::01:00:09 ===
>   ** Generic server <0.2713.0> terminating 
>   ** Last message in was {timeout,#Ref<0.0.0.26000>,start_beam}
>   ** When Server state == {state,{global,ts_mon},
>                                  10000,undefined,"centos-181",undefined}
>   ** Reason for termination == 
>   ** {error,timeout}